# repeating this script not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to repeat this but I am not getting the results desired, Basically the `:google` data replace works however the `:wow` doesn't and neither does the `:hi` is there something that I'm doing wrong that would prevent this from working.

```
 var newdata = data.text[i].replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");
 newdata = data.text[i].replace(/:hi/g,"<img src=\"hi.gif\"></img>");
 newdata = data.text[i].replace(/:google/g,"<img src=\"google.gif\"></img>");

 $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ newdata +"</p>"));
```

> *:google is the only working .replace*

Comment: They all work, but you are only storing the last one which is `:google`. You are constantly completely replacing the value of `newdata`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thankyou, how would I store them all then so they all display images instead of the words?

Comment: Replace `data.text[i]` with `newdata` on your 2nd and 3rd lines.

Comment: I see a `loop` in your near future!

Comment: I've added it as an answer, note that @JarrodRoberson answer will also work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the value of `newdata` each time, so you only see the value of the last `replace()`. It's applying the replace on the original data you have which is `data.text[i]`. Instead you need to use the new modified variable `newdata` on each replace:

```
var newdata = data.text[i].replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");
newdata = newdata.replace(/:hi/g,"<img src=\"hi.gif\"></img>");
newdata = newdata.replace(/:google/g,"<img src=\"google.gif\"></img>");
```

Comment: Is something wrong with this answer? If so mention it in a comment and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are doing, you are just overwriting `newdata`, last one is the only one you will see evidence of. This is exactly why reusing variables is poor practice, it creates a state machine that is not always obvious what is intended to happen or why what is intended to happen is not happening.

If your intention is to apply all three of the `.replace` on the original data in stages, this is what you need to do.

```
var wow = data.text[i].replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");
var hi = wow.replace(/:hi/g,"<img src=\"hi.gif\"></img>");
var google = hi.replace(/:google/g,"<img src=\"google.gif\"></img>");

$('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ google +"</p>"));
```

*the step debugger in your browser is your ally and would have shown you what was actually happening*

If you are trying to apply the `.replace` individually then you should do something like the following.

```
var wow = data.text[i].replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");
var hi = data.text[i].replace(/:hi/g,"<img src=\"hi.gif\"></img>");
var google = data.text[i].replace(/:google/g,"<img src=\"google.gif\"></img>");
```

then do whatever you need to do with the individual variable references.